# Getting different results from attribute.dataset and jquery .data() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

I was getting unexpected results and when I debugged into the problem, I found that I was not getting right data-attribute value by Jquery **.data()** method. It was pretty clear that value was not right and when I changed my code to **attribute.dataset.name** (native property of an element) It returned me the expected value.

[here's the screenshot of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afv21.png)

Any ideas, what could be the possible reason because I am using a lot of data-attributes in my situation and don't want to change the code everywhere I am accessing data-attributes by Jquery .date() method.

Comment: please add some real code with explanation of error so that we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.data(prop)` and `.dataset[prop]` can be different if:

- The HTML dataset contains one value
- jQuery's `.data` has been called on the element previously to store a value associated with the same key

Example:

```js
$('div').data('foo', 'newFooVal');

console.log($('div').data('foo'));
console.log($('div')[0].dataset.foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-foo="oldFooVal"></div>
```

jQuery's `.data` will retrieve:

- Any previous value set with `.data` (which will be completely unrelated to the dataset)
- If no previous value has been set to that key with that element, the value for that key in the dataset will be returned

So you have to be careful with what setting and retrieving. It's admittedly not entirely intuitive, since it'll do something different in different situations.